# Why is my array of files not appending to FormData?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

I've been stuck on this for three days. I've tried pretty much every solution on this site and I even asked for help on other websites.

I'm trying to send a post request with a FormData object as the body. Everything works except for the fact that my image array is hitting the server as undefined/empty, which results in the document being saved to the database with an empty array [] as the value for the image key.

Testing the route on Postman it works perfectly and saves the array of images that I send. So there is a problem with my front end code. Yes, the name of my HTML file input is the same as the upload.array(name, number) on the back end. Yes, the Mongoose model sets the key:value pair as an array. Yes, all of multer is set up perfectly (was working fine with single uploads, and works fine for multiple uploads when tested with Postman.)

As far as I can tell, the problem definitely lies in the code below. It seems like my array of files is not appending to the FormData.

```
// POST FUNCTIONALITY

//initializing Post Article variables
let formContent = "";
let fileInput = [];

//listening for value changes in the Post Article form
function formDataChange() {
    document.getElementById("tArea").addEventListener("change", function(){
      formContent = document.getElementById("tArea").value;
    });
    document.querySelector("input[type='file']").addEventListener("change", function(){
      fileInput = Array.from(document.querySelector("input[type='file']").files);
      console.log(fileInput); //this console log outputs the array of files showing that the event listener at least is working properly
    });
};
formDataChange();

//listen for POST button
function listenPostArticle() {
  document.getElementById("postArticle").addEventListener("click", postArticle);
};
listenPostArticle();

//fire off POST request
function postArticle () {

let formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append("content", formContent);
formdata.append("jwt", token);

fileInput.forEach((f) => {
  formdata.append("image[]", f);
})


let req = new Request("http://localhost:8080/api/articles/", {method: 'POST', body: formdata,
headers:{'Authorization': "Bearer " + token}});

fetch(req)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    res.redirect("http://localhost:5500");
  })
}
```

Mongoose Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  content: {type: String, required: true},
  image: {type: []},
  jwt: {type: String}
});

module.exports = Article = mongoose.model("article", ArticleSchema);
```

Route:

```
router.post("/", upload.array("image", 5), (req, res) => {
    const newArticle = new Article({
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      content: req.body.content,
      image: req.files,
      jwt: req.body.jwt
    });
    newArticle
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      res.json({ message: "Article posted!"}); 
    })
});
```

[Screenshot of Postman working successfully. Key field for images is "image"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCHjU.png)

Comment: `console.log(req);` and `console.log(formdata)`. Make sure they're being set properly. You could also try using a [MITM proxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) to check the data being set to ensure it's being set correctly.

Comment: Please show the ajax code too

Comment: Do you mean the Express code? I just put my Mongoose+Express code up

Comment: Can you post from the Chrome (etc) network tab what `exactly` is being sent to the server from the client? What is the content of that post request?

Answer (score 0):

In you header add multipart/form-data

```
let req = new Request("http://localhost:8080/api/articles/", {method: 'POST', body: formdata,
headers:{'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}});
```

Comment: Can you post your backend code? I mean how are you expecting the data, also a screenshot of postman while posting the request will be helpful.

Comment: Added the back end code, will get the Postman screenshot up in a few mins. Thank you for trying to help!